# OS X Database Tools?

Tags: macos, database-design

I'm looking for a database visualization tool for OS X. [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) looks promising, but the binaries provided are Intel only and I haven't been able to get the source to compile on PowerPC yet. Are there any other database visualization tools out there for OS X? What other tools do you use for database development/administration?

I'm looking for applications native to OS X (i.e. it uses Cocoa). It doesn't have to be free, and I no longer need it to be able to run on PowerPC. I would like to know if there are other programs used besides Sequel Pro and MySQL Workbench as MySQL Workbench was only ported to OS X recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Querious](http://www.araelium.com/querious/), a fantastic Cocoa app for MySQL database management. A veritable Delicious Library of database management apps.

Comment: It doesn't offer database visualization, but it's the only native application mentioned that I have not heard of.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) for MySQL and [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/) for SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) to access our Postgres and Oracle.  I haven't tried for MySQL, but there' is a Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are heaps of database design tools for Mac but I'm not sure what percentage of them runs on PPC. Look around [apple downloads page](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/).

Answer (score 0):

[Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). Supports all databases that can be connected via Javas JDBC.

Comment: I use Squirrel and like it, but find it somewhat prone to hanging on long operations or connection timeouts and suffers from some other quirky behavior ("Could not close some connections, do you still want to quit?" - answering No still quits.)

Answer (score 0):

There are [plenty of Eclipse plugins](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewcatlink-cid-3.html) for database visualization and manipulation (search stack-overflow for recommendation). Most of them work on Mac OS X. Most of them connect via JDBC, which means you just need the [Connector/J for MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html).

[OpenOffice Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) is another interesting alternative.

Comment: @holms the original questions did not ask for Cocoa-native tool. This was an edit that was added after I gave the answer.